# how to set ansible fact from an array with whitespace

Tags: arrays, json, ansible, ansible-facts

i am trying to set facts from a json array, since the key contains space i am unable to parse, can someone help me here,
i want to set fact as "name": "IN-FG-04" when "vdom": "vdom-shop"

Please see my sample playbook entry

```
  - name: Iterate JSON
    set_fact:
      app_item: "{{ item['scope member'] }}"
    with_items: "{{ result.results }}"
    register: app_result
```

please see the json input and this is an output of my previous task

```
{
    "msg": {
        "ansible_facts": {
            "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
        },
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "msg": "Custom Query Success",
        "results": [
            {
                "name": "FG-04-Policy",
                "obj ver": 3,
                "oid": 1196,
                "package settings": {
                    "central-nat": "disable",
                    "fwpolicy-implicit-log": "disable",
                    "fwpolicy6-implicit-log": "disable",
                    "inspection-mode": "proxy"
                },
                "scope member": [
                    {
                        "name": "IN-FG-04",
                        "vdom": "vdom-shop"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "pkg"
            },
            {
                "name": "FG-04-DC",
                "obj ver": 23,
                "oid": 1216,
                "package settings": {
                    "central-nat": "disable",
                    "fwpolicy-implicit-log": "disable",
                    "fwpolicy6-implicit-log": "disable",
                    "inspection-mode": "proxy"
                },
                "scope member": [
                    {
                        "name": "IN-FG-04",
                        "vdom": "vdom1-dc"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "pkg"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: although this is quite a good exercice for practicing loops, you should definitely consider fixing the previous task giving the result or [write your own filter](https://www.ansible.com/blog/how-to-extend-ansible-through-plugins).

First of all, you are using `register` on a `set_fact` task. It is not an error in itself but is of very limited interest. This will register if you correctly assigned a value to a variable, not the values themselves. So you will never get the expected result with this.

What you want to do is to append items to a list while you are looping over your json in the `set_fact` task. This is done by initializing your `set_fact` variable to an empty list with the [`default`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defaulting-undefined-variables) filter on first loop and appending a new list with your items.

Moreover, since you need to look at several level of your object at the same time to take decisions, you need to use a [`subelements`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/subelements.html) loop: loop level 0 on each result and level 1 on each element of the `scope member` list. On each iteration, you will append an object to the list. In the example below, I used the [`ternary`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8) filter to decide which name to include.

```
---
- name: SO Test
  hosts: localhost

  vars:
    result: {
      "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
      },
      "changed": false,
      "failed": false,
      "msg": "Custom Query Success",
      "results": [
        {
          "name": "FG-04-Policy",
          "obj ver": 3,
          "oid": 1196,
          "package settings": {
            "central-nat": "disable",
            "fwpolicy-implicit-log": "disable",
            "fwpolicy6-implicit-log": "disable",
            "inspection-mode": "proxy"
          },
          "scope member": [
            {
              "name": "IN-FG-04",
              "vdom": "vdom-shop"
            }
          ],
          "type": "pkg"
        },
        {
          "name": "FG-04-DC",
          "obj ver": 23,
          "oid": 1216,
          "package settings": {
            "central-nat": "disable",
            "fwpolicy-implicit-log": "disable",
            "fwpolicy6-implicit-log": "disable",
            "inspection-mode": "proxy"
          },
          "scope member": [
            {
              "name": "IN-FG-04",
              "vdom": "vdom1-dc"
            }
          ],
          "type": "pkg"
        }
      ]
    }

  tasks:
    - name: Get all names + vdom as requested in a list
      set_fact:
        app_result: >-
          {{
            app_result
            | default([])
            +
            [{
              'name': (item.1.vdom == 'vdom-shop') | ternary(item.0.name, item.1.name),
              'vdom': item.1.vdom
            }]
          }}
      loop: "{{ lookup('subelements', result.results, 'scope member') }}"

    - name: show result
      debug:
        var: app_result
```

Which results in

```
PLAY [SO Test] *****************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Get all names + vdom as requested in a list] *****************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'name': 'FG-04-Policy', 'obj ver': 3, 'oid': 1196, 'package settings': {'central-nat': 'disable', 'fwpolicy-implicit-log': 'disable', 'fwpolicy6-implicit-log': 'disable', 'inspection-mode': 'proxy'}, 'type': 'pkg'}, {'name': 'IN-FG-04', 'vdom': 'vdom-shop'}])
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'name': 'FG-04-DC', 'obj ver': 23, 'oid': 1216, 'package settings': {'central-nat': 'disable', 'fwpolicy-implicit-log': 'disable', 'fwpolicy6-implicit-log': 'disable', 'inspection-mode': 'proxy'}, 'type': 'pkg'}, {'name': 'IN-FG-04', 'vdom': 'vdom1-dc'}])

TASK [show result] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "app_result": [
        {
            "name": "FG-04-Policy",
            "vdom": "vdom-shop"
        },
        {
            "name": "IN-FG-04",
            "vdom": "vdom1-dc"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: thanks for the response, can we retrieve main item name example: ` if "vdom": "vdom-shop" ` then name should be `'name': 'FG-04-Policy'` if `"vdom": "vdom1-dc"`  then name should be `"name": "FG-04-DC"`  sample output  `    "msg": [
        {
            "name": "FG-04-Policy",
            "vdom": "vdom-shop"
        },
        {
            "name": "FG-04-DC",
            "vdom": "vdom1-dc"
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: @athi: answer edited. But please edit your question and add the expected output there.

Comment: thanks for the update.  but this result is not matching conditionally. example 1: if vdom = vdom-shop then result should show only FG-04-Policy.  example2 : if vdom = vdom1-dc then result should show only "FG-04-DC"

Comment: You should be careful when  providing your requirements so they are clearly understandable (you still did not edit your original question to fix that for example). Please read [How to I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex). On my side, I think I have spent enough time to give you all the clues you need to finish your homework. Please share the result you will find [with your classmate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56215022/how-to-set-ansible-conditinal-search)

Answer (score 0):

The snippet below

> set fact as "name": "IN-FG-04" when "vdom": "vdom-shop"

```
- name: "set fact as name: IN-FG-04 when vdom: vdom-shop"
  set_fact:
    name: "{{ result.results|json_query('[].\"scope member\"[?\"vdom\"==`\"vdom-shop\"`].name')|flatten|first }}"
- debug:
    var: name
```

gives:

```
"name": "IN-FG-04"
```

Comment: thanks for the update and this is working as expected,but need one modification. now the result is `"name": "IN-FG-04"` instead of this  required `name": "FG-04-Policy"`